# How to perform two different aggregation on one measure and further aggregate the results to view as one aggegated measure in Tableau

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, visualization, aggregation, measure

I have a dataset where I wish to place the data in two groups, based on the value name. I then wish to average the result for one group and sum the result for the other. Finally, I wish to sum these two to create a barchart.

**updated**
Here is the data

```
    Id  Total   Avail   Date    group   used
     A  10      5   9/1/2020    Group1  5
     A  40      20  9/1/2020    Group1  20
     B  20      10  9/1/2020    Group2  10
     B  10      5   9/1/2020    Group2  5
     B  10      5   9/1/2020    Group2  5
     A  20      10  9/1/2020    Group1  10
     A  20      10  9/1/2020    Group1  10
     B  10      5   9/1/2020    Group2  5
     B  10      5   9/1/2020    Group2  5
```

This is what I have done

1.
First create calc. field named : **group** - group the data into groups

```
IF [Id] = 'A' THEN 'Group1'
ELSEIF [Id] = 'B' THEN 'Group2'
ELSE 'none'
END
```

2. 

Then create calc. field - **sum_avg** sum of Group1 (A) columns and take average of Group2 (B)

```
CASE [group]
WHEN 'Group1' THEN { FIXED [Id]: SUM([Avail])}
WHEN 'Group1' THEN {FIXED [Id]: SUM([used])}
WHEN 'Group1' THEN {FIXED [Id]: SUM([Total])}
WHEN 'Group2' THEN { FIXED [Id]: AVG([Avail])}
WHEN 'Group2' THEN {FIXED [Id]: AVG([used])}
WHEN 'Group2' THEN {FIXED [Id]: AVG([Total])}
END
```

Here is that result:

[image]

Desired result:

I wish to **add** the *Group1(sum)* and the *Group2(avg)* for the Avail, Used and Total so that
the final chart combines the two blue values and combines the green values.

```
The SUM of Group1A Avail = 45 and the AVERAGE of G Avail Group2 = 6
So I wish the Avail section (blue) of the barchart to be: 51


and the Used (green) should be 51 as well
with the total as 102 (Ill add to tooltip)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated- I am still researching this and any suggestion is appreciated

*****UPDATE*****

I have a dataset where I wish to reflect the totals from the custom SQL query. Here is some sample data:

```
Size Tb   Val       type           Group      Sum_AVG    SKU      Last_refreshed

270       90.5      Free_Space_TB  Group2     90.5       Excel    9/1/2020
270      179.5      Used           Group2     179.5      Excel    9/1/2020
```

Here is the custom query output

[image]

Here is my view

[image]

The avail and used appear when I hover over, but how would I include the total?

[image]

[image]

This is the calculation I am using (thanks to help from a SO member):

```
{SUM({Fixed [type]: ZN(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))})
+
sum({Fixed [type]: zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))})}
```

SUM_AVG is:

```
zn(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))
+
zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))
```

I am doing something wrong, because it is totaling up across all the columns, when I just want the total for each column.

**(Used was created from using a custom query)**

Comment: My apologies @anilgoyal I have updated this post

Comment: see edited answer please.

Comment: How can anyone assist you when the data you gave pertained to only one date and your view consists of multiple dates.  It is always advisable to give minimal reproducible example so that all the twists can be understood. Nevertheless try including [date] in fixed statement. Or please give some fair amount of data to work with.

Comment: ok @AnilGoyal, I was thinking the concept was the same. Everything is working except my totals calculation totals across all the blue columns and not for each one. I will have to update post . thank s

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal add date in fixed statement, similar to this? {SUM({Fixed [type]: ZN(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))}) + {SUM({Fixed[date]: ZN(sum(if[Group]= 'Group1; then [Val] end))})
+
sum({Fixed [type]: zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))})} ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is proposed-

- The total column is of no use.  Please drop it.  It will unnecessary increase the size of your data.  (for tooltip I'll tell you how to do it).

sample data used

```
+----+-------+--------+------+
| Id | Avail | group  | used |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| A  | 5     | Group1 | 5    |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| A  | 20    | Group1 | 20   |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| B  | 10    | Group2 | 10   |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| A  | 10    | Group1 | 10   |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| A  | 10    | Group1 | 10   |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    |
+----+-------+--------+------+
| B  | 5     | Group2 | 5    |
+----+-------+--------+------+
```

- pivot two columns (`used` and `avail`).  A gif is included below

[image]

- Create a calculated field `CF` as

```
zn(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))
+
zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))
```

- Drag `AGG(CF1)` to rows shelf and to text also, `type` to colors in marks card; you'll get your desired view with 51 and 51 values in both types `used` and `avail`.

[image]

- for `total` tooltip i.e. `102` create a calc field `total` as

```
{SUM({Fixed [Type]: ZN(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [Val] end))})
+
sum({Fixed [Type]: zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [Val] end))})}
```

- add this field to details in marks card (instead of tooltip as you do normally).
- click on tooltip and edit calculation there as per taste.  I have edited it like

```
Out of total  <total> TB SKU, <AGG(CF1)> was <Type>
```

You'll get tooltip like this.

[image]

and

[image]

**P.S./EDIT**  This is regarding pivoting data in tableau.  Instead of connecting to complete data through SQL connection, you can modify the sql query by following the instructions mentioned [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.htm).  Two options-

- **Option-1** creating used column in sql and pivoting in tableau.  While importing data/creating connection use this query-

```
select ID, date, avail, total - avail AS used, group from table_name
```

- **Option-2** pivot the data in sql itself.  Use this query then-

```
select ID, date, avail as val, "avail" as type, group from table_name
UNION
select ID, date, total - avail AS val, "used" as type, group from table_name
```

thereafter you can proceed in tableau.

See the tableau uses long data format and your data is in wide format. You should keep your SKU memory allocation in rows instead of columns so whenever you'll need a division, adding an extra field type to marks card will do the job. If instead you will have it in columns, these are always two separate measures whereas in actually it is one measure. I suggest you to read some articles on internet about tidy data format, wherein you'll understand what to keep in rows, columns and column_names clearly. Reshaping data to a correct and tidy format solves a lot of problems.

Remember, if there is any value in variable(column) name you have to pivot a data. Here `used` and `avail` are variable values and therefore these cannot be in column_names (i.e. variable names) I think I am pretty clear.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you @anilgoyal let me try this please

Comment: OK I see- do I have to drop the total? what if I needed this? I will try this

Comment: Ok do I need to pivot? or could I just utilize the groups I created - (CASE statement)

Comment: Ah ok thank you so much for your knowledge  @anilgoyal -  I will try this.

Comment: Do you just highlight the columns and then right click to pivot? I do not see option when Ctrl on both column @anilGoyal

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much . You are an expert with tableau- I will keep learning thank you

Comment: Is it not possible to do pivot on calculated field? - I think maybe this is why its not letting me @anilgoyal

Comment: Hello @anilgoyal if I cannot do the pivot, can I still utilize this calculation (without the pivot)'? 
zn(sum(if [Group]= 'Group1' then [?] end))
+
zn(avg(if [Group] = 'Group2' then [?] end))

Comment: ok couldnt I do SUM(ZN(IF CONTAINS([group], 'Group1')
THEN [Avail] END))
+
AVG(ZN(IF CONTAINS([group], 'Group2') 
THEN [Avail] END))

Comment: ok I see, hmm I wonder how I can do this. The data has to come 'live' from my SQL server database and I do not have tableau prep

Comment: ok thank you @AnilGoyal this would be helpful if it can be completed in Tableau

Comment: Thank you @anilgoyal for your assistance- I really appreciate

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal could you please assist me, as my total calculation isnt working- I can show you what I have done in the updated post above.